# getting error - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Productxxx')] on reading field value on JSON parsed result

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am not able to read the ProductSKU in LWC component JS file from parsed JSON result as below:

1. In LWC js file I get below result after execution of line below:

   ```javascript
   const datarecs = JSON.parse(test);
   ```

   ```text
   {index: 3, ProductSKU: null, Qty: null, UnitPrice: null, Batch: null}
   ```
2. But when I try to fetch ProductSKU as below, it throws error

   > Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ProductSKU')

   ```javascript
   console.log('datarecs==>',this.datarecs.ProductSKU);
   ```

Can anyone guide me on this? I have checked the similar posts it doesn't helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declared a constant `const datarecs` but you are referring to `this.datarecs`

`this.datarecs` refers to a member of the outer class.

`datarecs` is member of the function that you are in.

So to fix, change `this.datarecs` to `datarecs`.

Comment: Thanks Casper. It worked